# В андроид вычислить сколько часов и минут осталось от времени указаного в TextView

Tags: android, java

Например, в TextView1 указано время "14-00". Bспользуя текущее время вычислить сколько осталось часов и минут до 14-00 и вывести его в TextView2. Tсли время позже 14-00 записать в TextView2 "Цирк уехал".

Comment: @rulita, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm");
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse("14-00");
long diff=System.currentTimeMillis()-date.getTime(); //разница в миллисекундах
```